# Query taking a long time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The below query taking more time to give results. This query in running inside the exists clause and also this query having stuff function.Is there any way to optimize or rewrite this query?.

```
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 
           FROM 
               (SELECT DISTINCT
                    F_ALIAS,
                    F_DATA_CODE,
                    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + A.F_DATA
                           FROM T_REP_DATA A
                           WHERE A.F_ALIAS = RPDS.F_ALIAS
                             AND A.F_DATA_CODE = RPDS.F_DATA_CODE
                             AND '1:WVTST{PROD006' = A.F_ALIAS
                           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value( '.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') F_DATA
                FROM T_REP_DATA RPDS
                INNER JOIN 
                    (SELECT DISTINCT F_CUSTOM2 
                     FROM T_MSDSTYPES 
                     WHERE (F_CUSTOM2 IS NOT NULL AND F_CUSTOM2 != '')) MT ON MT.F_CUSTOM2 = RPDS.F_DATA_CODE and RPDS.F_ALIAS = '1:WVTST{PROD006') RPDS_CUSTOM2)             
           WHERE RPDS_CUSTOM2.F_DATA LIKE 'MANU'
```

Comment: Well, for one: if you only want to check the **presence** of some data, using `IF EXISTS()`, then you really don't need to select multiple columns and do the whole `STUFF(......)` circus - you're **only** checking whether at least one row exists that matches the `WHERE` condition; no column selection necessary, you can skip that whole part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is probably not correct at all (`LIKE 'MANU'` actually means `= 'MANU'`), but perhaps your query is doing (or is supposed to be doing) nothing more than this:

```
AND EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM T_REP_DATA RPDS
  INNER JOIN T_MSDSTYPES MT
    ON MT.F_CUSTOM2 = RPDS.F_DATA_CODE
  WHERE RPDS.F_ALIAS = '1:WVTST{PROD006'
    AND RPDS.F_DATA = 'MANU'
)
```

more specific answer requires more details.

Comment: Thank you.I will remove the distinct clause and stuff function in thatmy query and i will use the above query.I hope above query also  will give same desired output..